# How to calculate vector potential $A$ from electric field $E$ in the field of strong field approximation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

In order to simulate higher harmonic generation (HHG) using the strong field approximation (SFA), we need to calculate vector potential $\textbf{A}$ from the electric field $\textbf{E}=E_{0}f(t)\cos(i\omega_{c}t+\phi_0) \textbf{e}_x$, where $\omega_{c}$ is the center wavelength of this pulse, $\phi_0$ is a global phase, and $f(t)$ is a function about time $t$. We know that
$$ \textbf{E} = -\nabla \varphi - \frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial t} $$
$$ \textbf{B}=\nabla \times \textbf{A}, $$
but how do we calculate $\textbf{A}$ from $\textbf{E}$?

Comment: 1. What is the $\mathbf{x}$-dependence of your electric field? 2. The LHS (vector) and the RHS (not a vector) of your "equation" $\mathbf{E}= E_0 \ldots$ do not match. 3. Which gauge condition for $\mathbf{A}$ and $\varphi$ do choose?

Comment: Because I am greenhand of this field, so I am very confuse about what the condition should I take, and the paper said the gauge is length gauge and in the field of Bern-oppenheimer approximation, so I want to know how to calculate it in different condition.

Comment: Maybe only consider linear polarization is much simpler.